# C# FirstOrDefault() not working even with using System.Linq

Tags: c#, .net, reference, using

Beginner to C# here: I want to only see the facilities where there is an employee with the same age as the current user.

For some reason `FirstOrDefault()` has a red line under it saying:

*'Facility' does not contain a definition for 'FirstOrDefault' and no accessible extension method 'FirstOrDefault' accepting a first argument of type 'Facility'could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?*

Here is the line:

`facilities = facilities.Where(facility => facility.Employee.FirstOrDefault().Age == (int)HttpContext.User.GetAge());`

At the top of the file, I have "using System.Linq" which I know is working because without it there is an error on Where. So, I am wondering what else could cause this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. First, you need to Filters a sequence of values based on a predicate and then return the first element of a sequence. [Read more here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=net-5.0)

```
facilities = facilities.Where(facility => facility.Employee.Age == (int)HttpContext.User.GetAge()).FirstOrDefault();
```

And this is more readable,

```
var userAge = (int)HttpContext.User.GetAge();
facilities = facilities.Where(facility => facility.Employee.Age == userAge).FirstOrDefault();
```

Agree with @Metro, You can simply use,

```
var userAge = (int)HttpContext.User.GetAge();
var facility = facilities.FirstOrDefault(facility => facility.Employee.Age == userAge);
```

Comment: 1. `facilities` is `IEnumerable`, whereas the result of the query is a single `Facility` - you cannot assign the single instance (`Facility`) to the enumerable variable (`IEnumerable<Facility>`). 2. The `Where` clause should be replaced with `FirstOrDefault`; there is no need to filter with `Where` and then return the first one, re: `FirstOrDefault` will perform the filter and return the first matching predicate.

Comment: I agree with @MetroSmurf, `Where()` should be replaced with `FirstOrDefault()` and your lambda-expression should be placed inside the `FirstOrDefault` invocation.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming facility.Employee is a list type:

```
var userAge = (int)HttpContext.User.GetAge();
facilities.Where(facility => facility.Employee.Any(e => e.Age.Equals(userAge)));
```

If not and there is only one employee per facility, then

```
var userAge = (int)HttpContext.User.GetAge();
facilities.Where(facility => facility.Employee == userAge);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are already iterating over `facilities` and I believe `Employee` property has one to one relationship with `Facility` class i.e. Employee is not a list.

Just below code will work

```
var emp_age = HttpContext.User.GetAge() as int;
facilities = facilities.Where(facility => facility.Employee.Age == emp_age);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because `facility.Employee` is not implementing the `FirstOrDefault` method. Probably it's not a `List/IEnumerable` (or `ICollection` in general).

You can instead compare by age first, then use `FirstOrDefault`

```cs
int age = (int)HttpContext.User.GetAge();
facilities = facilities.Where(facility => facility.Employee.Age == age).FirstOrDefault();
```